# openFileOutput is undefined for the type

Tags: android

I'm following a tutorial where in his `openFileOutput` there's a suggestion to surround it with try catch. But in my code, it only suggest to create method `openFileOutput(String, int)`. I'm using a `fragment` btw. Here's my code:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener { 

    TextView text_fname, text_lname;
    EditText edit_fname, edit_lname;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {    

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

        text_fname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text_lname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);

        edit_fname = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        edit_lname = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit2);

        Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        String fname1 = text_fname.getText().toString();
        String fname2 = edit_fname.getText().toString();

        String lname1 = text_lname.getText().toString();
        String lname2 = edit_lname.getText().toString();    

        FileOutputStream fos=openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

}
```

Comment: There's no `openFileOutput` method in `Fragment` class, so this method must be created somewhere before in the tutorial or just missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line to the following:

```
FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```